# Marker is not showing in google map and it doesn't use gps

Tags: android, dictionary, location, marker

It doesn't show the marker for the location "Ahmedabad" and also doesn't show the current location and also doesn't use gps. what is wrong with the code ?

public class GoogleMap extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap googleMap = null;

final LatLng Ahmedabad = new LatLng(23.022214, 72.542786);

public GoogleMap() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_google_map, container, false);

    onMapReady(googleMap);


    return v;

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap;
    processMap();
}


public void processMap() {
    if (googleMap != null) {


        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Ahmedabad).title("Ahmedabad"));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        // TODO: Consider calling


    }


}
```

}

My manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="canonical.FriendlyMap">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".NavigationDrawer" >

        </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCmsRCp1EuFTOsYUTGMPcpV2aLRfzJWLKM"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You don't call onMapReady, that is handled via the OnMapReadyCallback. You need to initialize the map with `MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_google_map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);`

Comment: where can I write that code ? And it suggest to use Android.support.v4 fragment instead of MapFragment